# Laravel model not get relations in resource api

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables that are related to each other by 3rd table (where only stores the ids) now seems i can't get my data out of third table in API resource file

## Logic

1. `Product` model (has many barcode)
2. `Barcode` model (belongs to product and belongs to outlet)
3. `Outlet` model (has many barcodes)
4. `outlet_products` table (stores `barcode_id` and `outlet_id`)

## Code

`Barcode model`

```
class Barcode extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function outlet()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Outlet::class, 'outlet_products', 'barcode_id', 'outlet_id');
    }
}
```

`Outlet model`

```
class Outlet extends Model
{
    public function barcodes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Barcode::class, 'outlet_products', 'outlet_id', 'barcode_id');
    }
}
```

`BarcodeResource`

```
class BarcodeResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $arrayData = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'sku' => $this->sku,
            'serial_number' =>  $this->serial_number ? (Int) $this->serial_number : null,
            'price' => (Int) $this->price,
            'discount' => $this->discount ? (Int) $this->discount : null,
            'product' => new ProductsResource($this->whenLoaded('product')),
            'outlet' => new OutletsResource($this->whenLoaded('outlet')),
        ];
        return $arrayData;
    }
}
```

> Now I am trying to get my product barcodes and name of each barcode outlet.

`Controller`

```
$products = ProductsResource::collection(Product::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with(['barcodes', 'barcodes.outlet'])->get());
```

and the result is:

[image: one]

**Any idea why i can't get my barcodes outlet?**

Comment: Hi. please paste your Product Model code

Comment: Can a barcode belong to many products? And can a barcode belong to many outlets?

Comment: If you need OneToMany relationships, your pivot table `outlet_products` is not required. And if you need ManyToMany relationships, your pivot `table outlet_products` is incorrect.

Comment: @LobsterBaz no barcode is only belongs to 1 product but during the te can be belong to several outlet let say from storage (outet a) send to store 1 (outlet b) or from store 1 to store 2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comment above:

- A `Product` has many `Barcode` and a `Barcode` belongs to a `Product`. They have a **One To Many** relationship.
- An `Outlet` has many `barcode` and a `Barcode` has many `Outlet`. They have a **Many To Many** relationship.

---

**Here's how to set the One To Many relationship.**

In your `Product` class:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function barcodes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Barcode');
    }
}
```

In your `Barcode` class, set the inverse relationship:

```
class Barcode extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

---

**Here's how to set the Many To Many relationship.**

In your `Outlet` class:

```
class Outlet extends Model
{
    public function barcodes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Barcode');
    }
}
```

In your `Barcode` class:

```
class Barcode extends Model
{
    public function outlets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Outlet');
    }
}
```

With a Many to Many relationship, you also need to create an intermediate table.

In this case, your pivot table will be `barcode_outlet`.

**Important:** Per Laravel convention, the intermediate table name must be in singular form and alphabetical order of the related model names (barcode_outlet in your case).

The intermediate table must have `barcode_id` and `outlet_id` columns. I will let you modify your migrations accordingly.

---

After setting the relationships, you will be able to use Eloquent to retrieve your models.

Example:

```php
$barcode->outlets;
// returns a Collection of outlets

$barecode->product;
// returns a Product

$product->barcodes;
// returns a Collection of barcodes

$outlet->barcodes;
// returns a Collection of barcodes
```